# При клике на button должны выполняться действия

Tags: javascript, html5

у меня в задании нужно сделать так, чтобы после проигрыша можно было запустить игру заново, но у меня не получается. Точно где ошибка я сказать не могу, потому что новичок в js. **Cуть проблемы**: когда игра проиграна появляется выбор сложности, но при нажатии ничего не происходит.**чтобы понять что не так, попробуйте запустить пример кода, прокликайте какую-нибудь и когда скажет сколько секунд вы прожили выберите сложность еще раз** [preview](https://yaroslav-teplyi.github.io/tama/index.html)

```js
'use strict';

let foodPg = document.getElementById('foodProg'),
  cleanPg = document.getElementById('cleanProg'),
  happinessPg = document.getElementById('happinessProg'),
  healthPg = document.getElementById('healthProg'),
  socializationPg = document.getElementById('socializationProg'),
  moneyPg = document.getElementById('moneyProg'),

  countFood = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50),
  countClean = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50),
  countHappiness = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50),
  countHealth = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50),
  countSocialization = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50),
  countMoney = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50),

  countSec = 0,
  isGameOver = true,
  isGameScore = true;

foodPg.value = countFood;
cleanPg.value = countClean;
happinessPg.value = countHappiness;
healthPg.value = countHealth;
socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
moneyPg.value = countMoney;

document.getElementById('easyLevelBtn').onclick = function() {
  start();
  setInterval(easyDiff, 5000);
  setInterval(duringLife, 1000);
  setInterval(gameOver, 100);
  setInterval(randomHelp, 60000);
}

document.getElementById('hardLevelBtn').onclick = function() {
  start();
  setInterval(hardDiff, 5000);
  setInterval(duringLife, 1000);
  setInterval(gameOver, 100);
  setInterval(randomHelp, 60000);
}

document.getElementById('ninjaLevelBtn').onclick = function() {
  start();
  setInterval(ninjaDiff, 5000);
  setInterval(duringLife, 1000);
  setInterval(gameOver, 100);
  setInterval(randomHelp, 60000);
}

function start() {
  document.querySelector('.start').hidden = true;

  let actions = document.querySelector('.actions'),
    style = actions.style;
  actions.classList.add('actions-on');
  if (isGameOver == false) {
    actions.classList.remove('actions-on');
  }
}

document.getElementById('eatBtn').onclick = function() {
  countClean -= 20;
  cleanPg.value = countClean;

  if (countFood <= 70) {
    countFood += 30;
    foodPg.value = countFood;
  } else {
    countFood = 100
    foodPg.value = countFood;
  }
}

document.getElementById('washBtn').onclick = function() {
  countHappiness -= 20;
  happinessPg.value = countHappiness;

  if (countClean <= 60) {
    countClean += 40;
    cleanPg.value = countClean;
  } else {
    countClean = 100
    cleanPg.value = countClean;
  }
}

document.getElementById('runBtn').onclick = function() {
  countFood -= 10;
  foodPg.value = countFood;

  if (countHappiness <= 85) {
    countHappiness += 15;
    happinessPg.value = countHappiness;
  } else {
    countHappiness = 100
    happinessPg.value = countHappiness;
  }
}

document.getElementById('doctorBtn').onclick = function() {
  countMoney -= 20;
  moneyPg.value = countMoney;

  if (countHealth <= 70) {
    countHealth += 30;
    healthPg.value = countHealth;
  } else {
    countHealth = 100
    healthPg.value = countHealth;
  }
}

document.getElementById('barBtn').onclick = function() {
  countMoney -= 20;
  countHealth -= 10;
  moneyPg.value = countMoney;
  healthPg.value = countHealth;

  if (countFood <= 90 && countSocialization <= 60) {
    countSocialization += 40;
    countFood += 10;
    socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
    foodPg.value = countFood;

  } else if (countFood > 90 && countSocialization > 60) {
    countFood = 100
    countSocialization = 100;
    socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
    foodPg.value = countFood;

  } else if (countFood <= 90 && countSocialization > 60) {
    countFood += 10;
    countSocialization = 100;
    foodPg.value = countFood;
    socializationPg.value = countSocialization;

  } else if (countFood > 90 && countSocialization <= 60) {
    countFood = 100
    countSocialization += 40;
    socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
    foodPg.value = countFood;
  }
}

document.getElementById('workBtn').onclick = function() {
  countSocialization -= 20;
  countFood -= 10;
  countHealth -= 10;
  healthPg.value = countHealth;
  socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
  foodPg.value = countFood;

  if (countMoney <= 50) {
    countMoney += 50;
    moneyPg.value = countMoney;
  } else {
    countMoney = 100
    moneyPg.value = countMoney;
  }
}

document.getElementById('buyBtn').onclick = function() {
  countMoney -= 20;
  moneyPg.value = countMoney;

  if (countFood <= 80) {
    countFood += 20;
    foodPg.value = countFood;
  } else {
    countFood = 100
    foodPg.value = countFood;
  }
}

document.getElementById('bussinessBtn').onclick = function() {
  countHealth -= 100;
  countMoney = 100;
  countHappiness = 100;
  healthPg.value = countHealth;
  moneyPg.value = countMoney;
  happinessPg.value = countHappiness;

  if (countSocialization <= 80) {
    countMoney += 20;
    socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
  } else {
    countMoney = 100
    socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
  }
}

function easyDiff() {
  countFood -= 3;
  countClean -= 3;
  countHappiness -= 3;
  countHealth -= 3;
  countSocialization -= 3;
  countMoney -= 3;

  foodPg.value = countFood;
  happinessPg.value = countHappiness;
  cleanPg.value = countClean;
  healthPg.value = countHealth;
  socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
  moneyPg.value = countMoney;
}

function hardDiff() {
  countFood -= 5;
  countClean -= 5;
  countHappiness -= 5;
  countHealth -= 5;
  countSocialization -= 5;
  countMoney -= 5;

  foodPg.value = countFood;
  happinessPg.value = countHappiness;
  cleanPg.value = countClean;
  healthPg.value = countHealth;
  socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
  moneyPg.value = countMoney;
}

function ninjaDiff() {
  countFood -= 7;
  countClean -= 7;
  countHappiness -= 7;
  countHealth -= 7;
  countSocialization -= 7;
  countMoney -= 7;

  foodPg.value = countFood;
  happinessPg.value = countHappiness;
  cleanPg.value = countClean;
  healthPg.value = countHealth;
  socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
  moneyPg.value = countMoney;
}

function duringLife() {
  if (isGameScore) {
    countSec += 1;

    if (foodPg.value <= 0 || cleanPg.value <= 0 || happinessPg.value <= 0 ||
      healthPg.value <= 0 || socializationPg.value <= 0 || moneyPg.value <= 0) {
      isGameScore = false;
    }
  }
}

function gameOver() {
  if (isGameOver) {
    if (foodPg.value <= 0 || cleanPg.value <= 0 || happinessPg.value <= 0 ||
      healthPg.value <= 0 || socializationPg.value <= 0 || moneyPg.value <= 0) {
      alert('You have been lived for ' + countSec + ' seconds')
      document.querySelector('.actions').hidden = true;
      document.querySelector('.start').hidden = false;
      isGameOver = false;
    }
  }
}

function randomHelp() {
  let a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (6 - 0) + 0);

  switch (a) {
    case 1:
      countFood += Math.ceil(Math.random() * (50 - 10) + 10);
      foodPg.value = countFood;
      break;
    case 2:
      countClean += Math.ceil(Math.random() * (50 - 10) + 10);
      cleanPg.value = countClean;
      break;
    case 3:
      countHappiness += Math.ceil(Math.random() * (50 - 10) + 10);
      happinessPg.value = countHappiness;
      break;
    case 4:
      countHealth += Math.ceil(Math.random() * (50 - 10) + 10);
      healthPg.value = countHealth;
      break;
    case 5:
      countSocialization += Math.ceil(Math.random() * (50 - 10) + 10);
      socializationPg.value = countSocialization;
      break;
    case 6:
      countMoney += Math.ceil(Math.random() * (50 - 10) + 10);
      moneyPg.value = countMoney;
      break;
    default:
      alert("Нет таких значений");
  }
}
```

```css
@import url(../fonts/fonts.css);*{margin:0;padding:0}body{font-family:'Open Sans';background:#f4f4f4;text-align:center;box-sizing:border-box}#wrapper{width:100%;height:100%;display:table;overflow:hidden;table-layout:fixed}.list{list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:0}.game{background-image:url(../images/bg/1.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:bottom;background-size:cover;height:700px;border-radius:5px;}.start{min-width:500px;margin:0 auto;background:#999b8cc9;border-radius:5px}.start__form{display:flex;justify-content:space-evenly}.actions{position:relative;display:none}.actions__btn{min-width:120px}.actions__list{padding:0;margin:0;}.actions__progress-bar{list-style-type:none;color:#fff}.actions-on{display:block}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <section class="game container">

    <div class="start">
      <h2 class="start__title">Choose your Tamagochi type:</h2>
      <form class="start__form">
        <input type="button" class="start__btn" id="easyLevelBtn" value="Easy level">
        <input type="button" class="start__btn" id="hardLevelBtn" value="Hard level">
        <input type="button" class="start__btn" id="ninjaLevelBtn" value="Ninja level">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <form class="actions__form" id="form">
        <input type="button" class="actions__btn" id="eatBtn" value="eat">
        <input type="button" class="actions__btn" id="washBtn" value="wash">
        <input type="button" class="actions__btn" id="runBtn" value="run">

        <input type="button" class="actions__btn" id="doctorBtn" value="visit doctor">
        <input type="button" class="actions__btn" id="barBtn" value="go to bar">
        <input type="button" class="actions__btn" id="workBtn" value="go to work">
        <input type="button" class="actions__btn" id="buyBtn" value="buy food">
        <input type="button" class="actions__btn" id="bussinessBtn" value="start a business">
      </form>

      <ul class="actions__list">
        <li class="actions__progress-bar">
          <span>food</span>
          <progress id="foodProg" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </li>
        <li class="actions__progress-bar">
          <span>clean</span>
          <progress id="cleanProg" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </li>
        <li class="actions__progress-bar">
          <span>happiness</span>
          <progress id="happinessProg" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </li>
        <li class="actions__progress-bar">
          <span>health</span>
          <progress id="healthProg" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </li>
        <li class="actions__progress-bar">
          <span>socialization</span>
          <progress id="socializationProg" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </li>
        <li class="actions__progress-bar">
          <span>money</span>
          <progress id="moneyProg" value="0" max="100"></progress>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </section>

</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: У вас объявлено много счетчиков через `setInterval`, но не видно, чтобы вы их сбрасывали через `clearInterval` при рестарте.

Comment: я не могу придумать логику как правильно их вписать

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов решения: 1) просто перезагружайте страницу; 2) перенесите таймеры во внутрь функций: вместо `setInterval(gameOver, 100);` используйте `gameOver(100)` и `function gameOver(time) {...}`; 3) я бы перешел на [классы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) и создавал подписчиков событий.

Comment: я и думал через классы, но не могу понять как они устроены, может быть, вы знаете хорошее видео или  статью?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/class https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes